# Errors in using fromtimestamp function in python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to use fromtimestamp function in python to convert datetime data into seconds. But, the error happens in certain points.
one example is

1478422800 and 1478422740 in seconds date.

although 1478422800 is bigger than 1478422740 by 60 seconds,
1478422800 is converted to (2016, 11, 6, 1, 0), and
1478422740 is converted to (2016, 11, 6, 1, 59)

Do you guys have any idea about that?

I inserted code below

---

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1.47842280e+09)

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1.47842274e+09)
```

Comment: output is 2016-11-06 09:00:00
2016-11-06 08:59:00   I don't see any problem

Comment: http://ideone.com/ySvKx4

Comment: Are you using python 3.2? For me, it still show the same problem.

Comment: I tried in both 2.7 and 3.2

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sb1iummsm5rdbx6/Screen%20Shot%202017-08-14%20at%207.44.35%20PM.png?dl=0    can you see this link? I am having same problem repeatedly, and my friend is too. as you can see in history log, the date goes back from 01:59:59 to 01:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly some sort of correction related to [daylight saving time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2016), which occurred on November 6, 2016 in the U.S causing all clocks to go back 1 hour when the time reached 2 am. It is most likely appearing inconsistently on different computers due to differing timezone settings.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I need to correct my timezone settings.

Comment: Actually, it can be solved by using 'datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp' function. Thanks.